# DV SSL Certificates

Tags: ssl, cpanel, whm

I have a small dedicated server with WHM/Cpanel, i run there some of the wordpress blogs, for example 1 blog is about specific hamsters and how people should take care of them and other blog is about body diet, what are the best foods for certain  person to maintain healthy body. I discovered trough WHM DV(Domain Validated) Certificate it's very cheap only 3 usd per domain, but i did some research and it seems that it should be that free.

So i bough 1 ssl certificate for hamster site and i'm wondering if i will buy another ssl certificate for diet site will google or some internet tool will be able  figure out that both sites belongs to me, because those sites are running on dedicated IP and for seo purposes it's very bad if SSL certificate would show some kind of info which associates myself with all those websites because some of the sites are similar niche.

So my questions:

Please correct me if I'm wrong on following:

As far my research went i figured out that DV certificate only validates domain, and thats it, even if you would change the servers IP you could transfer that SSL to other IP, and there is no way for anybody figure out that sites which runs under DV certificate belongs to the same person, together giving that google SEO boost (nobody knows by how much) giving a SSL on your site.

Please advise.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Domain-Validated certificates validates the ownership of a domain, and they are not connected with a specific IP address. This is correct.

If you move the site to a different server, you can reuse the same domain.

However, you should be aware that there are plenty of ways to potentially correlate together two sites. One example is WHOIS data.

Regardless, even some SSL certificate analysis may actually correlate a certificate. For example, some CA requires you to provide extra information about an organization (O) or organizational unit (OU) when requesting the certificate.

Most [DV certificates are logged](https://crt.sh/) and it's possible to fetch some details from the issued certificates that can correlate the owner of two apparently different domains.

To answer your question, it's still possible to correlate to match some data from different sources to potentially identify that two sites belong to the same person.

Comment: Thank you for time writing the answer, it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificate is issued on FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name) and it does not relate to your IP address. The DV SSL is known to its domain name and not the IP address. Domain validation bears primary verification and can be issued within few minutes in which the certificate authority verifies the domain ownership of SSL applicant. Even when you move the site, the domain will be still active.

Now coming to question of Google’s HTTPS priority, Google has given HTTPS as a ranking signal and currently the authority is considering around 1% of global queries but later on the percentage of secured website will have higher ratio as the need of secured environment over the web is increasing.